# How to generate custom URLs with Docpad?

Tags: url, routes, docpad

I'm looking to remove redundant directories from my output URLs. This seems like it would be straightforward, but I can't seem to figure it out.  Specifically:

This: .com/tmj/recipes/cocktails/rye/toronto.html

Should be more like this: .com/cocktails/rye/toronto.html

I've got a bit of a funny set up using a git submodule that requires the actual src documents to be organized a special way. Anyone know how I can get around this?

Comment: Glad you solved that dkr. :) Could you make an answer with your solution and accept it so that it closes this question?

Comment: Sure, just wasn't sure this was the best answer. :)

Comment: Well if something better comes up you can always accept that one later. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the URLs I wanted by reworking the src config. This was a bit counter-intuitive to me, but now that I see it working it makes sense. Essentially I told DocPad to ignore the extra directories, and generate the site with out them. Here is the code I used, to be placed in the docpad config (docpad.coffee.)

`documentsPaths: [  # default
            'documents/the-mason-jar/recipes', 'pages'
        ]`